# load latitude and longitude from API before map loads Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, viewdidload, cllocationcoordinate2d

I'm trying to show a map with two markers with longitudes and latitudes that are retrieved from API.

the function that gets the longitudes and latitudes is called in `Viewdidload`

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getCurrent()
```

also the code to show the map with markers in `viewdidload` so my full code looks something like this:

```
var longFamily  = ""
let latFamily = ""
var latShop = "" 
var longShop = "" 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getCurrent()
    let coordinate₀ = CLLocation(latitude: CLLocationDegrees(Int(latFamily)!), longitude: CLLocationDegrees(Int(longFamily)!))
    let coordinate₁ = CLLocation(latitude: (Int(latFamily)!, longitude: (Int(longFamily)!))
    let distanceInMeters = coordinate₀.distance(from: coordinate₁) // result is in meters
    let floatDistance = Float(distanceInMeters)


    // get two markers with shop and client locations



    map.delegate = self

    // 2.
    let sourceLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Int(latFamily)!, longitude: (Int(longFamily)!)
    let destinationLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: (Int(latShop)!, longitude: (Int(latShop)!)
```

I know there is something I have to do to get the data before the map loads but not sure where. I'd appreciate your help

GetCurrent function calls API :

```
 Alamofire.request(url!, method: .get, parameters: param,encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: headers).responseJSON { response in



        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            //Handle the results as JSON


            let data = JSON(value)
            self.LongShop = data["shopLong"] 
     // this is for family locations too
```

Comment: So you basically want to load the coordinates from an API (not MapKit), before the map loads so you can display them?

Comment: @mcjcloud  yes the API will give me the coordinates and the map is (MapKit) is in the view

Comment: IMO this is just a design problem. Design your app to show a loading screen while you're waiting on the API call to return, then in the completion handler when you get the successful call back with the geo-coordinates, present a new VC with the map. Also you probably shouldn't use integers for latitude and longitude.

Comment: thanks I solved the issue with the loading. now , as you just mention , I have an issue with latitude and longitude because Int doesn't put the location on the right places. What is the best conversion ? Or how to convert my string from API to valid latitude and longitude

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the coordinates before the map loads, you want to make the API call before the view is loaded (before `viewDidLoad` is called). You could try `viewWillAppear`, but depending on the response time from the API, this may be unreliable. I would suggest making the call to the API as soon as you have the data to do so. Get `param` from the user or desired source before hand (possibly in a different view), and pass it to the map view in the `prepareForSegue` function:

1. Add a global variable to the map view (MapViewController.swift for example)

   ```
   class MapViewController {
       var param: Any?    // replace Any with the desired data type
       /* rest of MapView code */
   }
   ```
2. Make the API call and pass in the previous View Controller and pass it to the MapViewController

   ```
   class PreviousViewController {
       var param: Any?    // replace Any with the desired data type

       override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           getFromAPI()    // getFromAPI being a function that makes the API call and assigns the param variable
       }

       func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
           if let dest = segue.destination as? MapViewController {
               dest.param = self.param
           }
       }
   }
   ```

On top of this, you can add features in which the MapViewController segue cannot be performed until `param` is not `nil`